# How to add eventsListenter to Flutter BetterPlayerPlaylist

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

Could someone help with showing how to add events listener for BetterPlayerPlaylist.
I wish to know when a video at a specified playlist index finishes so I can pause or stop player, display a different page/widget, then come back to the player page to resume with the next video.

this works fine with the regular BetterPlayer - but can't get it to work with BetterPlayerPlaylist

i have tried this in initState, but both don't work

```
    _betterPlayerController =
    BetterPlayerController(_betterPlayerConfiguration);

    _betterPlayerController.addEventsListener(_handleEvent);
```

OR THIS

```
    _betterPlayerPlaylistController!.betterPlayerController!.addEventsListener(_handleEvent);
```

Here's the _handleEvent code. Nothing is printing. i have debugged and it's not even coming in here.

```
    void _handleEvent(BetterPlayerEvent event) {
    events.insert(0, event);

    ///Used to refresh only list of events
    _eventStreamController.add(DateTime.now());
    if (event.betterPlayerEventType == BetterPlayerEventType.play) {
      print("######################### Currently playing video: " +
      _betterPlayerPlaylistController!.currentDataSourceIndex.toString());
    }

    if (event.betterPlayerEventType == BetterPlayerEventType.changedPlaylistItem) {
      print("######################### Chnaging playlist item: " +
          _betterPlayerPlaylistController!.currentDataSourceIndex.toString());
    }

    print("*********************** event id: " + events.toString());
    }
```